# Userena Template Directory

Tags: python, django, templates

I've gotten userena successfully installed and I've copied the entire userena template directory over to my app (which is not named userena but rather accounts, so the directory the templates are in is `/accounts/templates/accounts/` ) but simply editing them reflects no changes. When I point my `urls.py` to

```
url(r'^accounts/signout/$', userena_views.signout, {'template_name': 'accounts/signout.html'})
```

It works, but only for that one file. Is there a way to have the entire app automatically refer to this templates directory? I thought about using `TEMPLATE_DIRS` but that would apply to the entire site and not this one app. Any solutions? Thanks for your help.

The view that calls this template:

```
def signout(request, next_page=userena_settings.USERENA_REDIRECT_ON_SIGNOUT,
        template_name='userena/signout.html', *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: How are you rendering the templates inside the `views.py`? Can you post that line?

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the whole function where you render the template?

Answer (score 0):

Put all userena templates in **accounts/templates/userena** instead of **accounts/templates/accounts**.
That should work.